# How to detect 6d pose of marker in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to detect 6d pose of a marker in opencv. How should I start with this. I am new to computer vision concepts. Can I do it using aruco marker library in opencv?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/dae/tutorial_aruco_detection.html)
 link has the information using opencv and aruco. You just need to use `cv::aruco::estimatePoseSingleMarkers` function.